# TestRail and JIRA integration with Robot Framework (RIDE IDE)

Tags: python, jira, robotframework, testrail, robotframework-ide

We are using RIDE IDE and are trying to integrate TestRail and JIRA. We have downloaded the TestRail API python file (testrail.py), but we are not able to import it in our project in RIDE.

Can we know how to implement the same.
Is there any steps or tutorial video for integrating TestRail and JIRA in RIDE ?

We are using RIDE 1.5.2.1 running on Python 2.7.12

Thanks

Comment: What does "not able to import" mean? Why aren't you able to import it? Does your test work when you run it from the command line? That should be the first thing to try, in order to determine if it's a problem with your test and/or library, or if it's a bug in RIDE.

Comment: Hi Bryan,
If I run the testcase from command line, the test case does run and the test case does get pass. But in the beginning in shows a warning.

[ WARN ] Imported library 'C:\Python27\testrail.py' contains no keywords.

I am trying to import the testrail library in my project.

Comment: You can't just import any python module and use it as if it were a keyword library.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a python library in a robot test, you will need to create your own library that provides keywords that use the library. You can't just import any random python library and expect it to work like a robot keyword library.